# Is it possible to convert an exe file to a jar file?

Tags: java, linux, executable

Is it possible to convert an exe file to a jar file?

Because I just made a game which is online and in .exe file format, and I have a server running linux. It may be possible to run the exe on the server, but one of the two ways would be very good for me!

So the ways are either:

1. Convert EXE to Java, or
2. Run EXE in Linux

Comment: Depends on what the .exe is. Is it a java application wrapper?

Comment: Why is your question title "Java to Exe..." while your actual question is "EXE to JAR"?

Comment: "convert [the] exe file to a jar file"? What is that even supposed to mean?

Comment: What programming platform/language did you use to create your game? Since you made it, you can probably just re-compile it for Linux. But we need more details to help you out.

Answer (score 6):

1. is impossible. EXE (actually PE) is the binary format used by the Windows family of operating systems. It contains assembled machine code and import and export tables to interact with the operating system. JAR contains java bytecode. Sadly, they are not compatible (actually the JVM generates machine code from the Java byte code on the fly, but the other direction is not possible AND makes very little sense, too …).
2. Check out Wine. It emulates part of the Windows API so it *can* run a subset of all native Windows applications.

Comment: Impossible?  Well, theoretically you could emulate the machine the .exe is designed for using java on a large enough sytem.  But that may not be realistically practical unless the hosting system has one or two orders of magnitude more resources than the originally targeted one. (ie, you could probably do it for a dos console app tolerably)

Answer (score 4):

You can run EXE on Linux under Wine (unless you use DirectX or alike), but what's the use of it? Is your game a server side of some distributed game (i.e. game server with clients running on the client computers)?

Upd: One more option is to run a virtual machine with Windows inside on your linux server. This can be more viable.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to convert an exe file
>   to a jar file.

Not unless the exe was made by Java source. and you have the source code. but then it isn't a conversion, its a recompilation.

> Run EXE in Linux

Wine will run windows executables. But if you have the source why not just run it with java?